# Generate unique combinations of non-unique elements

Tags: python, combinations

Say I have a string `aaaaaaaabbbbccdefg` with many duplicates elements. How do I efficiently generate all possible combinations of elements? Their order does not matter.

My case should yield `9*5*3*2*2*2*2=2160` possibilities: `a` can be chosen 0 to 8 times, `b` 0 to 4 times, `c` 0 to 2 times and `d`, `e`, `f`, `g` all 0 or 1 times.

I tried [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) but it doesn't handle duplicates efficiently and only returns combinations with some fixed length. The [`powerset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe solves the latter, but not the first issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found [the solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/195397/182108) on Code Review myself. The trick is to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

s = Counter('aaaaaaaabbbbccdefg')  # Or Counter({'a': 8, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 1})
gen = [''.join(Counter(dict(zip(s.keys(), p))).elements()) for p in product(*[range(n + 1) for n in s.values()])]
```